# dojo.cookie(id) not able to look up cookie by id intermittently

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
_setPrintExportCookieInterval: function(/**String*/requestId, /**function*/closePopup) {
    //have the interval autoexpire after some amount of seconds
    var count = 0;
    var intervalMs = 2000;

    var intervalId = self.setInterval(function() {
        var reportCookie = dojo.cookie(requestId);
        console.debug('requestId ' + requestId);
        if(reportCookie || count > 300000) { //5 mins
            //if there's a status failure, don't close the window
            console.debug('reportCookie ' + reportCookie);
            if(reportCookie == undefined){
                console.debug("print/export request returned with undefined status ");
            } else if(reportCookie == "success") {
                closePopup();
            }  else{
                console.debug("print/export request returned with nonstandard status " + reportCookie);
            }
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
            //delete the cookie
            dojo.cookie(requestId, null, {path: "/", expires: -1});
            //destroy the iframe
            //dojo.destroy(dojo.byId(requestId));
        };
        count+=intervalMs;
    }, intervalMs);

    return intervalId;
},
```

I'm having problems with the above javascript function.  The problem generally is that sometimes:

```
var reportCookie = dojo.cookie(requestId);
```

returns `null`, but when I look in my browser's debugging tool I'm able to see that the cookie exists with a value of `success`.  This happens one in every 10 times this function is called.  Any ideas why `dojo.cookie()` is not able to look up the cookie by ID only some of the time?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you specify the path when you are retrieving the cookie, otherwise it defaults to the current location. This will allow you to get the Cookie from any path within your domain.

`dojo.cookie(requestId, null, {path: "/" });`

Comment: Worked for me when I made sure to set the path to "/" when setting the cookie (not getting).